# NullPointerException error while adding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am having problem with implementing `barcodefragmentlibv2` into my project. As a name says and from previous experience I know that I can add it into fragment. However, I am still getting `NullPointerException` error when I am trying to get this fragment to work with my app.

This is a part of a code responsible for barcode fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
//...

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements IScanResultHandler {
    BarcodeFragment fragment;

    public static CameraFragment newInstance() {
        CameraFragment fragment = new CameraFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    public CameraFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.include_qrfragment, container, false);
        fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
        fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
        return view;
    }
//...
}
```

Error appears in line:

```
fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);
```

I've also tried replacing

```
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
```

to

```
getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
```

but the result is this same.

Below are layout files:
fragment_camera

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".CameraFragment">

    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        layout="@layout/include_qrfragment" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:background="#99FFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/msg_default_status"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

include_qrfragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:name="com.abhi.barcode.frag.libv2.BarcodeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

At the beginning I've mentioned that from my own experience that this is possible. The truth is that I've built app utilizing this feature some time ago using eclipse and now I am using Android Studio - maybe there is a problem?

**EDIT 1:**

This is the whole error's stack trace:

```
06-22 23:05:56.804  30578-30578/myapp.com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at myapp.com.test.CameraFragment.onCreateView(CameraFragment.java:34)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you please post the whole stacktrace?

Comment: @ElDuderino I've added as requested.

Comment: What's in line 34? `getActivity()....` or `fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);` ?

Comment: @KirillK `fragment.setScanResultHandler(this);`

Comment: Documentation states that nested fragments inflation from XML [is not possible](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments). It can only be done dynamically. You mention that  you've used to have it working, but it might be enforced now if you run newer version that in the past, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to lie in this line:

```
fragment = (BarcodeFragment)getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.sample);
```

Your fragment is not yet appended to the activity as `getActivity()` is **null** at this point.

Perhaps you should move that particular  code to `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that then `NullPointerException` would be pointing on this line, because you can't call method (`getSupportFragmentManager()`) on null.

Comment: Yes, you cannot call any method on null objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should only inflate the layout at the CreateView, like this:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null);

}
```

The rest of your code, you should put it in the onActivityCreated as @waqaslam said.

You are getting a null pointer because there is no layout inflated yet.

Comment: I've checked it - still not work, and still this same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have read your responses, and now I am assuming you have tried or moved code of getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().`findFragmentById` into `onActivityCreated`.

The only suspect I see without loading up your project is the **GUI ID** itself. You named it `sample` or `R.id.sample`, which is a suspect in some projects. It is possible that you have another UI element having the same name/ID. If so, that UI *cannot be converted* to a fragment. My suggestion is to change the name of the ID (with unique name), and use it with `findFragmentById()`.